# How do I refresh a tab control page after a database update

Tags: database, refresh, updates, tabcontrol, tabpage

Using Visual Studio community 2017, winforms, C# and MySql DB.
I have a tab control page that displays the playlists created from the DB.
When I delete a playlists, it's removed from the DB, but is still visible in the tab page.
I created a button to try all refresh, update scenarios I could think of to no avail.
PlayListLoad() is my function that creates and populates my playlists.
Thanks for your help.

```
private void RefreshBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PlayListLoad();
        tabPage3.Update();
        tabPage3.Refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer through a lot of searches and try/error.
I just needed to clear the controls before updating.

```
private void RefreshBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabPage3.Controls.Clear();
    PlayListLoad();
    tabPage3.Update();
    tabPage3.Refresh();
}
```